# '<<' & '>>' operators overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've been writing a complex numbers header from scratch for a school class but I'm stuck on the extraction and insertion operators overload, I've been reading a lot about that topic but I still don't get it

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &tmp, Cmplx &param)
{
    tmp<<param.Re<<"+"<<param.Im<<"i";
    return tmp;
}
friend istream& operator >> (istream &tmp, Cmplx &param)
{
    tmp>>param.Re;
    tmp>>param.Im;
    return tmp;
}
```

But when I try to compile I get.

```
no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << Cmplx<vartype>::operator+(Cmplx<vartype>) [with vartype = long double](Cmplx<long double>(((const Cmplx<long double>&)((const Cmplx<long double>*)(& B)))))'
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
The Implementation:

```
#include"cmplx oper.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
Cmplx<long double> A, B;
cin >> A;
cin >> B;
cout<<(A+B)<<(A-B)<<(A*B)<<(A/B)<<(A+B).norm<<(A+B).pol<<(A+B).conj<<(A+B).re<<(A+B).im<<endl;
getch();
return true;
}
```

Also the modification, I changed the parameter to const:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &tmp, Cmplx const &param)
{
    tmp<<param.Re<<"+"<<param.Im<<"i";
    return tmp;
}
```

Still not working

EDIT 2:
I broke down the cout line and found that the problem was a pair of methods in my class, not actually the use of the '+' operator.
I still don't know why but at least I could compile.

Also, I wonder if I can get an specific style input for my class, I mean something like

```
scanf("%d+%di",Re,Im);
```

But using cin (I cannot, or at least I don't know how to use `scanf` since It's a template, and it's pretty awkward to write an specific cin for each type of data)

EDIT 3:
I found the problem, a lack of parenthesis.

Comment: What is the declartion of Cmplex? is it templated?

Comment: @GWW: That's quite clear from the error.

Comment: yup, here's the declaration itself:
`template <typename vartype>
class Cmplx
{
    public:
    vartype Re, Im;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't show your use of it, but in this case I can see what's up.

You're doing something like `std::cout << (Cmplx1 + Cmplx2);`.

The result of `(Cmplx1 + Cmplx2)` is a temporary; temporary expressions *may not* be bound to references.

For example:

```
int f() {
   return 3;
}

int& x = f(); // ill-formed
```

However, as a special piece of C++ magic, temporaries *can* be bound to `references-to-const`:

For example:

```
int f() {
   return 3;
}

int const& x = f(); // magic!
```

The temporary then lives as long as the `reference-to-const` does.

If your operators take references to `const` complex objects, then you can bind a temporary as the second parameter:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Cmplx const& param)
{
    os << param.Re << "+" << param.Im << "i";
    return os;
}
```

Conveniently, you ought to have done this in the first place as you will not be modifying `param` (and, in an `operator<<`, never should).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't really get this. I've modified my header so it looks like this:
`friend ostream& operator << (ostream &tmp, Cmplx const &param)
    {
        tmp<<param.Re<<"+"<<param.Im<<"i";
        return tmp;
    }`
also, the implementation:
`#include"cmplx oper.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Cmplx<long double> A, B;
    cin >> A;
    cin >> B;
    cout<<(A+B)<<(A-B)<<(A*B)<<(A/B)<<(A+B).norm<<(A+B).pol<<(A+B).conj<<(A+B).re<<(A+B).im<<endl;
    getch();
    return true;
}
`
Nevertheless it doesn't works

Comment: @Juan: "it doesn't works" isn't very helpful; regardless, I can't see anything there that should prevent your code from building.